# Does Disabled attribute work with hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden field

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = "test1" id = "test1" value ="<?php echo $val ?>" >
```

Now iam   applying disabled attribiute through Jquery . Will the Disabled attribute work for hidden fields or it will work only for input type = text

```
$('#test1').attr('disabled','disabled');

if($("#radio_no:checked") && $("#someelement").attr('value')==="abc"){                         
            $("#test1").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#test1").attr('class', 'TextBox');           
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is that code, the code that tries to set the attribute?  Is it in an event handler?  Are you 100% sure that it's really executing?  Are you sure it's finding the input field (i.e., is "$('#test1').length" equal to 1)?

Comment: @pointy:Updated the question  if I have a radio button  checked with id of radio_no than iam doing set of operations

Comment: Well I guess you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It will work fine for hidden fields, preventing their inclusion in a form POST.

The strange myth about having to set the attribute to the string, "disabled", is, well, a myth.  Set it to either `true` or `false` to be clear.  The string "disabled" works because it's a non-empty string, and when cast to boolean it's `true`.  If you were to set it to "no" or "false" or "absolutely not", you'd also disable the input.

*edit* — to be clear, set the disabled attribute just as in your example, except:

```
$('#test1').attr('disabled', true);
```

*edit again* — and to those misguided people who disagree with my statement about how (in **JavaScript**, not in any page source language) one should use `true` and `false` for the "disabled" attribute, I would direct you to [the appropriate section of the W3C DOM Level 1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-798055546#ID-6043025), where the "disabled" attribute is clearly typed as a boolean, not a string.  Once the browser has parsed your pristine, standards-compliant source, be it HTML4, XHTML, HTML5, or whatever, the specific rules for *that* context no longer matter.  We're talking about setting the **DOM** attribute "disabled" from JavaScript here, so the appropriate standard to reference is the DOM spec.

Comment: @pointy: How can i apply in my current statement . Can you be more clear

Comment: I'll go ahead and play devil's advocate and say "I disagree!" to your second paragraph.  It's more important in my book to remain clear to the XHTML standard, which dictates that attribute minimization is not allowed and thus your HTML attribute should read: `disabled="disabled"`  jQuery might do this for you in some weird way, but I'm of the opinion that it's important to specifically set it to the XHTML standards-compliant value of 'disabled'.

Comment: @Adam Terlson Once the page source has been parsed, the standard for the source language is irrelevant. What matters is the semantics of the DOM.  Also, who uses XHTML anymore?  It's 2011, come join us in the sunny world of HTML5!

Comment: @pointy:I applied the same thing but still it is transferring the value to server side

Comment: @Derby then perhaps your `<input>` element doesn't have the "id" you think it does, or perhaps you've used the same "id" for multiple elements. The "disabled" attribute on hidden fields absolutely, positively, definitely works when it's set properly.

Comment: @pointy: I have  the id attribute same as name >i dont know what the problem i s

Comment: That's fine - I think you probably just need to do some debugging to make sure that the code is doing what it *looks* like it's doing. What happens if you add `alert($('#test1').attr('disabled'));` right after the line where you set it? (Or "console.log()" if you prefer ...)

Comment: @Pointy It's true that the HTML is no longer used, but to call it "irrelevant" isn't quite being honest.  It's relevant in terms of clarity and consistency.  The programmer writes the HTML and they write the JS, they don't write how the DOM is structured, thus consistency and clarity is achieved by keeping the HTML and JS semantics the same.  And who uses XHTML?  Oh, only about 60% of... everyone... is using transitional or strict explicitly.  HTML5 is a whopping 5%, though is of course still awesome. (http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo)

Comment: @Adam Terlson well I used the word "irrelevant" because as far as the actual technology involved is concerned, it is in fact irrelevant. The string "disabled" is definitely converted to a plain boolean when the actual attribute assignment is made. Using that convention in the context of DOM programming - which is what we're talking about - makes things really clumsy if you want to, for example, turn the attribute on or off based on some condition. In my opinion, following "rules" that actually make programming harder isn't of any benefit to anybody.

Comment: Also, I think it's important that programmers really know what's going on. Yes, it makes the XHTML programmer's world a bit more consistent to set the attribute to "disabled", but it's not really honest. The code actually being written - some JavaScript to manipulate a DOM element attribute - is in a different context than the original page code, just like the server-side code is a different context, and has its own set of rules to follow. Dragging in conventions from different domains when the actually relevant technology really doesn't understand or care is always an anti-pattern.

Comment: You make a sound point.  The bit about enabling is definitely a good consideration.  You've made me re-evaluate the meaning to life, the universe and everything.

Comment: *tips hat* Good day to you, Sir.

Comment: Not wishing to reignite such a politely concluded debate, but I just happened to notice that even if you use a boolean (as I do), jQuery (I'm using 1.6.4) will sneakily set `disabled` to `"disabled"` anyway. Looks like you can't win this one.

Comment: It seems to do that for all boolean attributes when it sets them via the "setAttribute()" DOM method.  If there's a property directly on the DOM element, then it sets that to honest-to-gosh `true` when you set it to a `true`, and when you set it to `false` it makes sure the attribute is completely removed. Note that jQuery treats anything that's not === `false` as true for booleans!

Comment: Note that there's a difference between the HTML/DOM attributes and DOM element properties. The attribute value is always a string, so boolean true would be converted to "true", or perhaps to the name of the property by either jQuery or the browser. The property on the other hand, which can be accessed through "$('input').prop('disabled', true)" or even $('input').get(0).disabled = true" does contain a boolean value. Internally the browser keeps the property and the attribute in sync and jQuery may play even more tricks for boolean attributes. This may also have changed in jQuery since 2011.