# Is there a way to not post the model value of the hiddenfield?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, hiddenfield, http-post

I have set of hiddenfields in my form to post the values of the read-only fields. But in some circumstances I wouldn't need to post the values. For example:

```
<div style="display: none;">
<!-- read-only controls -->
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.DeviceName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.DeviceName)
</div>
```

In the above example, I have hidden the above div using JQuery, but the value of the hiddenfield within the div is still posted.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586648/does-disabled-attribute-work-with-hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the input [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html). Disabled inputs do not get submitted to server

Comment: Note: The disabled attribute will not work with <input type="hidden">. - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: My bad, wrong link. Don't quite believe everything that is written on w3schools. Probably they meant that disabled is unusable for hidden fields. I updated the link, take a look. And this definitely works